# Why the wrong answer in integral calculus?

Tags: calculus, integration

Calculate the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region about the $x$-axis, and bounded by $y=x^2+1, y=3-x^2$.

[image: My graph.]

My calculations:
$V=\pi \int_a^b f^2(x) dx; \; V = V_1 + V_2 = \pi \int_{-1}^1 (3-x^2)^2 dx - \pi \int_{-1}^1 (x^2+1)^2 dx;$

$V_1 = \pi \int_{-1}^1 (3-x^2)^2 dx = \pi \int_{-1}^1 (9-3x^2-3x^2+x^4) dx = \pi (9x-2x^3+\frac{x^5}{5} \; |_{-1}^1 )=14.4 \pi;$
\begin{align*}
V_2 & = \pi \int_{-1}^1 (x^2+1)^2 dx\\
    & = \pi \int_{-1}^1 (x^2+1)(x^2+1) dx\\ 
    & = \pi \int_{-1}^1 (x^4+x^2+x^2+1) dx\\ 
    & = \pi\left(\frac{x^5}{5}+\frac{2}{3} x^3+x \; \bigg|_{-1}^1\right)\\
    & = \pi\left(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{2}{3}+1+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{2}{3}+1\right)\\             
    & = 2\pi\left(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{2}{3}+1\right)\\
    & =2\pi\left(\frac{3}{15}+\frac{10}{15}+1\right)\\
    & =\left(2+\frac{26}{15}\right)\pi;
\end{align*}

My answer: $V=14.4\pi - (2+\frac{26}{15})\pi;$, but this answer does not fit.

Comment: Do you know what the "correct" answer is? If so, could you comment what it is?

Comment: No, I don't know. I insert this value into the response field in the test, the program calculates the value, and rejects my answer.

Comment: I didn’t check your every step, but your work seems correct. Why do you believe that your answer is incorrect?

Comment: This is not my opinion, this is the result of checking the program.

Comment: Have you tried writing your answer as $\frac{32\pi}{3}?$

Comment: I checked it, but it's also a miss.

Comment: @Dhdh If I understand the program's algorithm correctly, it can't fail because of an incorrect fraction entry

Comment: Isn't $3+10+15=28$? Not $26$?

Comment: Why: 3+10+15? I don't see this part.

Comment: The next to last line of your post: you have $2\pi (3/15 + 10/15 + 1)$.  Since $1=15/15$ adding the fractions should get you $28/15$, but you write it on the last line of your post as $26/15$.

Comment: `2\pi(\frac{3}{15}+\frac{10}{15}+1)`?

$$2\pi(\frac{3}{15}+\frac{10}{15}+1)$$

Comment: Yes, that's the one.

Comment: @postmortes ``https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*pi%283%2F15%2B10%2F15%2B1%29%3D%282%2B26%2F15%29pi``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's worth noting that your method, while completely correct (both in result and in detail as far as anyone has found), is far more laborious (and hence more error-prone)  than it needs to be.
In this case, the "washer method" is easier.

For the washer method, we note that a given value of $x$ the disk inside the curve $y=3-x^2$ has area $\pi(3-x^2)^2$ and the disk inside the curve $y = x^2 + 1$ has area $\pi(x^2 + 1)^2$; then we remove the smaller disk from the larger disk, leaving a "washer" (also called an annulus), which is the shape we get when we take the line segment from  $(x,x^2 + 1)$ to $(x,3-x^2)$ and rotate it around the $x$-axis.

The area of the washer is 
$$\pi(3-x^2)^2 - \pi(x^2 + 1)^2 = \pi ((3-x^2)^2 - (x^2 + 1)^2)$$
(in general, $\pi(r_1^2 - r_2^2)$ where $r_1$ is the larger radius and $r_2$ is the smaller),
which we integrate from $-1$ to $1.$ Note that this is *exactly* equivalent to your method, since

$$ \int_{-1}^1 (\pi(3-x^2)^2 - \pi(x^2 + 1)^2)\,\mathrm dx
= \int_{-1}^1 \pi(3-x^2)^2\,\mathrm dx - \int_{-1}^1 \pi(x^2 + 1)^2\,\mathrm dx. $$

As with the disk method you used, the integral is usually simplified by taking the constant factor $\pi$ outside:

$$ V = \pi \int_{-1}^1 (r_1^2 - r_2^2)\,\mathrm dx
 = \pi \int_{-1}^1 ((3-x^2)^2 -(x^2 + 1)^2)\,\mathrm dx. $$

Now here's the neat thing about this method for this problem. Note that

\begin{align}
(3-x^2)^2 - (x^2 + 1)^2
&= (3^2 - 2(3)(x^2) + (x^2)^2) - ((x^2)^2 + 2(1)(x^2) + 1^2) \\
&= (9 - 6x^2 + x^4) - (x^4 + 2x^2 + 1) \\
&= 9 - 6x^2 + x^4 - x^4 - 2x^2 - 1 \\
&= 8 - 8x^2.
\end{align}

So we just need to integrate

$$ \pi\int_{-1}^1 (8 - 8x^2)\,\mathrm dx, $$

which is a lot less work than two integrals with both $x^4$ and $x^2$ terms in them as well as constant terms.

Comment: Another point of view of the original question is that OP could have carried out this same simplification starting from their equation $V = V_1 + V_2 = ...$ and then using your second displayed equation.

Comment: @LeeMosher That's true. The "washer method" is hardly a unique method of its own; you might say it's merely a way to nudge someone into combining and simplifying the integrals before integrating, which is something you _could_ do merely by manipulating the integrals without ever thinking about a "washer."

Comment: You wrote: "you have a last-minute arithmetic error", and this?

Comment: I understand Your method, but the answers are identical. Can you tell me where my mistake is?

Comment: In other words, instead of doing $\int f_1 dx - \int f_2 dx$, do $\int (f_1-f_2)dx$; subtract first and then integrate, rather than doing two integrations and then subtracting the results.

Comment: On second examination I agree with the result shown in the question above--I typed it incorrectly the first time I tried to evaluate it. I notice in a comment that the online checker also rejected the answer after it was simplified to a simple ratio of integers times $\pi.$ Possible explanations are (1) there's some subtlety in how the answer was requested, e.g. they want the result divided by $\pi$, or (2) whoever put the answer key in the software got it wrong. You've put so much effort into this, I think you could post a screenshot of the question and see if anyone can figure out what's up.

Comment: @DavidK Thank you, I will insist that the teacher disassemble this task.